# Factor into: active or passive?

Tags: passive-voice

From BBC News:

The team's campaign director said in a statement that "phony ticket requests ***never factor into*** our thinking" as entry to rallies is on a first-come first-served basis.

From what I know, we "factor something into another." So, should it have been, "***have/has never been factored into*** our thinking," instead?

Comment: It's a different sense of "factor".  And "factor into our thinking" is an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Not Passive.

Verbs that act this way are quite common. I'm sure there is a technical name but I don't know it. An important requirement is that they have a transitive and an intransitive version. Here are a few examples:

> He changed his socks.
>
> He changed after the accident.

> The water boiled.
>
> I boiled the water.

> The life-raft deflated.
>
> The deckhand deflated the life-raft.

> The house burned down.
>
> The arsonist burned the house down.

In business jargon, there is a tendency to use more and more words like this even if they don't traditionally have this form.